# Error implementing shared preferences in kotlin jetpack compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to store and access data within the app (so that it is saved even after closing the app). I have the below code but I'm running into an error (also shown below). The tutorial I was following used `ContextAmbient.current` in the line I commented in but I believe that is depreciated, so I used `LocalContext.current`. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
class PreferencesManager(context: Context) {
    private val sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences =
        context.getSharedPreferences("Preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

    fun saveData(key: String, value: String) {
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.putString(key, value)
        editor.apply()
    }

    fun getData(key: String, defaultValue: String): String {
        return sharedPreferences.getString(key, defaultValue) ?: defaultValue
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenView() {
    val preferenceManager = remember {
        PreferencesManager(LocalContext.current) // I'm getting an error here
    }
    val authKey = remember {
        mutableStateOf(preferenceManager.getData("authKey", ""))
    }

    Column {
        Text(authKey)
    }
}
```

Error: Composable calls are not allowed inside the calculation parameter of inline fun  remember(crossinline calculation: () -> TypeVariable(T)): TypeVariable(T)

Comment: You don't need to remeber value received from shared preference.

Comment: as @ChiragThummar has written: just your make val prefMngr  = PreferencesManager(LocalContext.current).

Answer (score 0):

**create a seperate variable** and pass it in the parameter, if you want to use instantiate the **PreferenceManager** only once along recompositions

```
@Composable
fun ScreenView() {
val context = LocalContext.current

//instead of passing directly the context ,create a variable

val preferenceManager = remember {
    PreferencesManager(context) 
}
val authKey = remember {
    mutableStateOf(preferenceManager.getData("authKey", ""))
}

Column {
    Text(authKey)
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to remember the value received from the SharedPreference because it is already not changing automatically.

Comment: due to jetpack compose nature ,when every recompose  happens , shared preferece instance may repeatedly called , creating un necessary instances, so better use remember,

Comment: Then you can put the Preferences Logic in ViewModel to You don't need to remember it.

Comment: bruh, i don't want to mess up with you,
in android there's no restrictions or right or wrong ways to do,
if a solution works for something , i better stick with that,
of course , i hope your solution also help people in some cases too.

Comment: Okay Cool Down Bro.. I'm just saying my point.